# Is it possible to make "abstract" xsl file

Tags: xslt

I have several xslt files whth similar code. I want to make generic file with some of this code and include it in these xslt's.

for example
generic.xsl

```
<xsl:template match="photos">  some general gode </xsl:template>
```

specific.xsl

```
include|import generic.xsl

<xsl:template match="photos">
 Here I need to invoke code from generic.xsl
 and add some specific code

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `<xsl:import>` to import XSLT templates from another file. You don't even need to defined the `<xsl:template match="photos">` in the outer stylesheet if this template exists in the inner one.

If you do (as Martin says) you can use `<xsl:apply-imports>` to call the imported stylesheet. This is due to the imported templates having a lower priority that the main ones. You can use `<xsl:include/>` instead if you want them all to have the same priority.

Alternatively you can defined a template by name:

```
<xsl:template name="process_photos">
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

And then call it using `<xsl:call-template>`. The current context is passed through to the called template:

```
<xsl:template match="photos">
    <xsl:call-template name="process_photos"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `<xsl:apply-imports/>` to "invoke" the template from the imported `generic.xsl`:

```
<xsl:template match="photos">
 <xsl:apply-imports/>
 and add some specific code

</xsl:template>
```

See also http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#apply-imports.